# Run a shell script from terminal

Tags: scripts, environment-variables, environment

I have a shell script at `/home/user/android-sdk-linux/tools`. I wish to run the script from the terminal by typing `ddms` so I added `:/home/user/android-sdk-linux/tools/ddms.sh`  to `/etc/environment` and run

```
sudo source /etc/environment
```

but ddms is fired from the terminal? Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your .bashrc file in vi or a text editor and add this line:

```
alias ddms='$HOME/android-sdk-linux/tools/ddms.sh'
```

Save the file and open a new terminal.

Comment: I edited .bashrc typed ddms on terminal and it says "bash: /home/gaurav/android-sdk-linux/tools/ddms.sh: No such file or directory"

Comment: @bcbc your suggestion does not help it is still returning "No such file or directory"

Comment: @codingcrow That was your edit. I just replaced `/home/user` with an environment variable that applies to any user. Unless you meant to hardcode to a user named `user`? If it says "no such file or directory", then that indicates that the `ddms.sh` script does not exist at that location.

Comment: @bcbc It works without `.sh` in the end.

Comment: @codingcrow Here's some more info on bash aliases:  http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html